# Integrating a function over a region

Tags: definite-integrals, vectors, surface-integrals

I have the following problem on a homework reading and am unsure how to attempt to solve it:

Integrate $f(x,y) = x^2\sin(y)$ over the graph of $g(x,y) = 2x-2y$, on the domain $[0,1]$x$[0,\pi]$.

The book has a sample formula, but I'm not understanding it and its not explaining any more than the following:
$$\int\int_S f(x,y,z)dS=\int\int_D \frac{f(x,y,g(x,y)}{\cos\theta}dxdy$$
$$N=-\frac{dg}{dx}i-\frac{dg}{dy}j+k$$
$$\cos\theta=\frac{N\cdot k}{||N||}$$
$$dS=\frac{dxdy}{n \cdot k}$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit** This is what I think each part is.
$$N = -2i+2j+k$$
$$\cos\theta = \frac{-2i+2j+k \cdot k}{||N||} = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$dS = \frac{dxdy}{\frac{-2i+2j+k}{3}\cdot k}= \frac{dxdy}{\frac{1}{3}}=3dxdy$$
Subbing all this in gives:
$$\int\int_S f(x,y,z)dS=\int\int_D 3*f(x,y,g(x,y)dxdy$$

I'm unsure of what to do from here to be honest, partially because my original function is only $f(x,y)$ not $f(x,y,z)$ and where the $n \cdot k$ went from subbing in dxdy.

Comment: The "F" on the right hand side of the first equation should be "f".

Comment: @JohnHughes fixed, but still confused xD

Comment: What you want to evaluate is on the left; the way to get that value is on the right. Do you know what "D" is in the right-hand expression? What about i, j, and k -- do you know what they denote? Can you compute dg/dx and dg/dy? Do you know what $N \cdot k$ means? How about $\|N\|$? Show us what you get for each part, and then tell us the bits you DON'T know how to handle. (You can edit your question by clikcing on "edit" just below it to show us what you CAN do).

Comment: @JohnHughes added what I think each step is, and where I get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

$$\int\int_S f(x,y,z)dS=\int\int_D 3*f(x,y,g(x,y)dxdy=\int\int_D 3*x^2\sin{y}dxdy$$
$$=\int3x^2(-\cos{y})dx$$
$$=x^3(-\cos{y})$$
Plugging in the bounds gives that the function is equal to 2.